# I need help finishing my palindrome checking python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm kind of a noob in python. This is a project I need to submit by midnight. the more I edit, the worse off it seems to get.

so here's my code:

```
import string

def palendrone():

    input = raw_input('give us some stuff and we will see if it is a palendrone:')
    lowercase = string.lower(input)

    new_string = ''
    markList = [".", " ", ";", ":", "!", "?", "/", "," , "#", "@", "$", "&", ")", "(", "\", '*', '^'"]

    for item in markList in lowercase:    
        del(item) in lowercase

    for letter in (lowercase):
        new_string += letter

    backwards_string = new_string[::-1]

    print new_string
    print backwards_string

    return backwards_string == new_string
```

I mostly need help trying to get rid of the punctuation. That has proven the most difficult for me.

What would be the best way to do that in this kind of situation?

Comment: Which *specific* part are you having trouble with? What's wrong with this code and how have you tried to fix it?  Please [edit] your question to provide these details (examples of incorrect output would be especially helpful).

Comment: Your consistent misspelling of "palindrome" is distracting; perhaps for a start, fix that.

Comment: palindrone is easier to type for me (lol), and it sounds the same in my head so i basically ignored the misspelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The logic you want is "for each item in markList, if that item exists in lowercase, delete it".

You made a good attempt at translating that into code, but unfortunately there is no such statement as `del(item) in lowercase`, to delete things from strings, you need to replace them with something else.

Here is how you translate that:

```
for item in markList:
   if item in lowercase:
      lowercase = lowercase.replace(item, '')
```

You don't need the second loop at all, instead:

```
backward_string = lowercase[::-1]
```

Comment: (commenting on translation) this worked, but a similar attempt of mine failed. when i went to do that, it said i needed 2 things inside the () [sorry, forgot exact wording] but i had both an item and a ''. does it really matter what you put before the '.replace'?

Comment: Yes, it matters a lot.  `'foo'.replace('a', '')` does nothing (returns "foo") while `'bar'.replace('a', '')` yields "br".

Answer (score 0):

> I mostly need help trying to get rid of the punctuation.

One of the ways to get rid of the punctuation is

```
import re
new_string = re.sub('[:?!/]', '', input)
```

Comment: it is not a sufficient answer. add explanations to your code please

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here :

1) You have to escape `\` which is done like `"\\"`.

2) Iterating over the input string and rejecting if something comes in `markList` is algorithmically better

```
import string

def palindrome():

    input = raw_input('give us some stuff and we will see if it is a palendrone:')
    lowercase = string.lower(input)

    new_string = ''
    markList = [".", " ", ";", ":", "!", "?", "/", "," , "#", "@", "$", "&", ")", "(", "\\", '*', '^']


    for letter in lowercase:
        if letter not in markList:
            new_string+=letter

    backwards_string = new_string[::-1]

    print new_string
    print backwards_string

    return backwards_string == new_string
```

**Note:** There are many ways to construct the cleaned string. For one such way refer to Antony's answer.